# Where to add BOLD Font?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Here we want to have Bold font for the facility name (data) i can't seem to able to make FONT added anywhere.

```
<Columns>
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FACILITY_ID" Visible="false">
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Facility Name" VisibleIndex="1">
                                    <CellStyle  HorizontalAlign="Left"></CellStyle>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <div style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; float: left;">
                                            <div style="float: left;">
                                                <dx:ASPxImage runat="server" ID="imgFilter" ToolTip="Show/hide grid filter" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/GridFilterButton.png">
                                                    <ClientSideEvents Click="ImageClick" />
                                                </dx:ASPxImage>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px;">
                                                Facility
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: It should be in the `CellStyle` element, no?

Answer (score 2):

Set `class="FacilityName"` for your `DataItemTemplate` and apply styles for it

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Facility Name" VisibleIndex="1">

 <DataItemTemplate>
    <span class="FacilityName"><%# Container.Text %></span>
</DataItemTemplate>
</<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

**css**

```
.FacilityName
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: like this is not good: <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" font-weight:bold Caption="Facility Name" VisibleIndex="1">

Comment: @Adams, Please refer https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewColumn_CellStyletopic

Comment: @Adams, Hope you are using DevExpress grid, so tagged the question with `DevExpress`